# Force felt by capacitor mounted on printed circuit board

Tags: forces, mass, acceleration

I have a printed circuit board with a surface mount electrolytic capacitor soldered to it. It has two spindly legs that hold up this can, so it can move back and forth on the legs' axis just slightly. This is enough for it to break off of the board during vibration testing.

[image]

The test is done by bolt mounting the PCB to a metal sled that is then vibrated back and forth randomly with a controlled acceleration (and I'm assuming deceleration) that does not exceed 3g. My capacitor broke off its leads at a much lower acceleration than the manufacturers' test data shows.

This brings me to my actual physics question. Because the acceleration of the sled is held constant, I'm curious if the mass of the sled used makes a difference in the force felt by the capacitor. If test house 1 used a 1 lb sled but test house 2 used a 40 lb sled, would the force felt by the capacitor be greater at test house 2 because the mass of the sled would require more force to reach that acceleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the acceleration (presumably measured on the sled) is the same, then the mass of the sled has no effect. It will take 40 times a s much force to accelerate the 40 lb sled. What is more likely to be happening is that at a particularly frequency, then mass of the cap and the spring constant of the legs will be such that you get metal fatigue from the induced oscillation of the cap relative to the sled..